# F.O.C of an utility function

Tags: statistics, functions, derivatives, utility

I have a Utility Function:

U(x_t,x_t+1) = ln(x_t) + E_t(ln(x_t+1))

I want to find the F.O.C

I need to know:

U'(x_t+1)

U'(x_t)

Can any1 help me do that?

Comment: E_t is the Expected Value.

Comment: What is FOC? And what have you done so far?

Comment: First Order Condition, the derivative.